# Angular 9 - js scripts not working (e.g. foundations or bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, zurb-foundation

First steps in Angular (doing an online course) and I keep thinking that my JS is not working. Because when I ng serve the below project is see the foundation styling (css), but the hamburger Icon is not opening/closing when I click it. The code is a sample from the foundation website.

**app.component.html looks like this**

```
<h1>This is the app</h1>

<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-nav" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="main-nav"></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="main-nav">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site title</li>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Through numerous topics in ended up with the following:

In styles.css I added

```
@import "../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css";
```

In angular.json I added

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js"
            ]
```

My own thoughts on it:

- Hamburger Icon and styling is there but its not opening/closing
- My angular.json file is not named angular-cli.json (like in other examples...WHY!?)
- I did not needed to ../ the scripts, they only compile like above (else error)
- working on Unix (ubuntu)
- Jquery version 3.5.1 and foundation-sites 6.6.3

Comment: "My angular.json file is not named angular-cli.json (like in other examples...WHY!?)": starting from Angular 6 `angular-cli.json` got renamed to `angular.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably possible to get this to work, but plain-old Bootstrap uses jQuery to manipulate the DOM (e.g. open/close your toolbar when you click the hamburger menu icon).

jQuery really should not be used with Angular, because it could interfere with Angular's maintenance of the DOM. (jQuery would change the DOM, and Angular wouldn't know about it).

For this reason, there are a couple of other projects, including ngx-bootstrap, that either use Bootstrap's css but implement the js functionality in terms of Angular directives, or which look and operate like Bootstrap and re-implement (at least partially) the css and the js.

Comment: Could you eleborate on this? Is Angular not practically capable to coop with other css framework that also use some form of JS? Is Angular meant to use the angular js, with only the css of other frameworks?

Comment: Yes, Angular "expects" to be in control of the DOM. So, to avoid unexpected behavior, all manipulation of the DOM should be done via the public Angular API. You may be able to get away with using another library, such as jQuery, to manipulate the DOM outside of the Angular framework, but it is not recommended. This question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512913/why-the-dom-operations-in-react-angular-via-external-libraries-like-jquery-is-n is about jQuery usage with React, but the considerations are largely the same.

Comment: Big 'aha' moment here. Thanks a lot, makes total sense now.

Comment: @furion2000 please consider upvoting the answer if it was useful and accept it if it solved the problem - this is a way to thank and give credit to the person who used their time to help you.